# How to prove that pork meat has parasites

Tags: parasitology

I suspect that the pork sold at a certain shop is infected with the parasite pork tapeworm (*Taenia solium*).

Is there a way I can prove this without special equipment? Would it work to leave the raw meat in the fridge (at 4 degrees Celcius, or higher?) for a week or so and the worms will come out of their eggs and grow big enough for the eye?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer**
*T. solium* infection can be identified in pork meat by visual inspection.

**Background**
The stage of the life cycle of the tape worm *T. solium* in pigs is characterized by *cysticerci*, which is the larval stage consisting of a [protoscolex](http://ivs.ku.dk/english/research/about_parasitology_and_aquatic_diseases/parasitic_zoonoses/cwgesa/cysticercosis_in_short/) (head) of the tapeworm. **Humans are the [definitive host](http://smallfarms.oregonstate.edu/beef/meat-measles)**, which means they are the species in which the parasite completes its life cycle, reaches adulthood and is able to produce eggs.

The larvae are observable in pork meat, and [cysticercosis is generally identified during slaughter](http://smallfarms.oregonstate.edu/beef/meat-measles) when cysts can be seen in muscle or organs (Fig. 1).

[image: cysticerci]
<sup>Fig. 1. *T. solium* cysticerci. (A): as seen in infected pork. (B): excised into a Petri dish. The white dot in each cyst corresponds to the scolex. Source: [Garcia et al. (2011)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3103219/#!po=3.84615)</sup>

It is not until these cysticerci are ingested by humans that the tape worm starts to develop fully into a [meters-long tape worm](http://web.stanford.edu/group/parasites/ParaSites2001/taeniasis/solium2.html), as it enters the next and final stage of its life cycle (Fig. 2).

[image: Taenia life cycle]
<sup>Fig. 2. *Taenia* life cycle. Source: [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/parasites/taeniasis/biology.html)</sup>

Hence, leaving the meat in the fridge will not induce growth, as a human is needed to induce outgrowth of the protoscolex into the mature tape worm.

**Reference**
[Garcia et al., *Lancet* (2011): **362** (9383): 547–56](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3103219/#!po=3.84615)